# Redirect all www and www to https and to specific files in subfolders but hide subfolder and extension without SEO double content penalty

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have been tearing my hair out for 20 hours with no success.

Assume the site is "example.com", and the working file is located in "example.com/subfolder1/kind-thoughts.php". I've been trying to come up with .htaccess rules to do the following:

1. If users just type "example.com/kind-thoughts" in address bar, it will automatically choose the secure https, and show "https://example.com/happy-thoughts" in the address bar. That means, without the "subfolder1" name, and without the "php" extension.
2. In the future, when I have more content, I want users to be able to type: "https://example.com/smart-thinking", and it will go to the file "https://example.com/subfolder2/smart-thinking.php".  Again, I want the address bar to show only "https://example.com/smart-thinking" , without "subfolder2" and without ".php".
3. I want the option, but not the requirement, to translate all other url reference that way, so that I can still use "fold/file.php"when I code internally. But I do need certain specific landing pages (such as those mentioned above) to have easy to have easily readable url and not show the subfolders they are under.
4. Since links like: "https://example.com/subfolder1/happy-thoughts.php" should still work if I need to reference it internally, so I need to somehow use  "301 redirect" in each case so as to avoid search engine penalty for double content.
5. As a total newbie, I tried copied/pasted all sorts of mod rewrite rules found here, but none achieved the above. Many thanks in advance for your kind advice!

Answer (score 0):

Try this rewrite rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*kind(.*)$ https://example.com/happy$1 [R,L]
```

It should transfer

```
example.com/kind-thoughts
```

to

```
https://example.com/happy-thoughts
```

Make sure to change `example.com` to your website.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My dumb question is whether the rewrite must have the R=301 flag to avoid "double content" penalty, since the same file is reachable with, and without, the ".php" extension. As a newbie, I don't have the ability to upvote your answer, but thanks very much for it!

Comment: @Jsproject it is my pleasure. No need for `R=301 flag`.